# Populate multiple textboxes on dropdownlist value in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have following Employee table,

```
  name      | experience |    location
  emp1           3 yrs             aaa
  emp2           2 yrs             bbb
  emp3           4 yrs             ccc
  emp4           1 yr              ddd
```

I have dropdown list which I have bound to **name** column of the table. 
I have 2 textboxes: `txtExp` and `txtLoc`. 
I want to populate textboxes to **experience** and **location** columns of the table on the basis of selected value from dropdown list, either by index changed of DDL or click event of a button.
i want to do it form a code behind file in asp.net c#

Comment: you want to do it with code or you want to fetch it from db?

Comment: so on index changed on the DDL for name, you want the othe two columns to populate your textboxes?

Comment: @raman , i want to do it with code, asp.net c#

Comment: @Derek , either by index changed of DDL or click event of a button.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: HTML - Have a drop down list that performs a post-back:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlName_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Emp 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Emp 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Emp 3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Step 2: C# - Execute the code that updates the controls:

```
protected void ddlName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Make a call to database/method to retrieve the Employee record based on 
    // Name/ID, which is bound to the drop down. Assumption that you will
    // use an object called Employee with name & location properties)
    Employee emp = GetEmployeeByID(ddlName.SelectedValue);

    txtExp.Text = emp.Name;
    txtLoc.Text = emp.Location;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show both the things then you have to concatenate the values where you are fetching the records for binding the dropdownlist, i am pasting the code, which will tell you how you can get the experience by name(selected value in dropdown)

first step is :

save the datatable from which you are binding the dropdown into ViewState

then on dropdown's selectedindexchanged event use the following code:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["dt"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string sqlFilter = "name = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
            DataRow[] data = dt.Select(sqlFilter);
            if (data.Length > 0)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = data["Exp"].ToString();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

or if you want to pass it to db to get the experience and location then do it in the following way:

```
clsArtBook obj = new clsArtBook();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = obj.getDetailsbyName(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
        TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["expeince"].ToString();
        TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["location"].ToString();
    }
```

create a stored proc which will get the details by name like :

```
create proc proc_GetDetailsByName
(
@name varchar(100)
)
as
if exists(select 1 from tblemployee where name=@name)
begin
 select location,experince from tblemployee where name=@name
end
```

it will resolve your problem